# overlayMapTypes using jquery-ui-map plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, jquery-plugins, overlays

I'm showing some map tiles with google maps api v3 and jquery-ui-map (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/)

And then I have this instruction:

```
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, trafficMapType);
```

And I don't know how to translate this using the jquery-ui-,ap plugin.

I have tried things like:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('overlayMapTypes','insertAt',google.maps.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, trafficMapType));
```

But it doesn't work.

Someone please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, trafficMapType);
```

Comment: Thank you now it's working!. I was using V2, I have to change to V3, modify my "callback"s for "bind" and use the "jquery.fn.gmap.js" instead. :)